# How do I run gbm.step (dismo package) with categorical variables in R?

Tags: r, dismo

I am analysing preferences towards urban vegetation and am trying to determine whether certain factors influence preference. I'm carrying out some boosted regression trees using the `dismo` package, as described by Elith et al. (2008). The example they use involves presence/absence data, so they use the bernoulli error family. All of my variables are categorical, but the `gbm.step` function will not allow me to use the multinomial error family. I have been told that if I do not specify an error family, and ensure that all of my variables have been structured as factors, that the function will assume the responses are multinomial. However, the code is still returning an error message. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Here is the code I am entering, and the error message that is being returned:

```
> rm.structure.tc02.lr01 <- gbm.step(
      data = my_data1, 
      gbm.x = 8:16,
      gbm.y = 2,
      tree.complexity = 2,
      learning.rate = 0.01,
      bag.fraction = 0.5)


GBM STEP - version 2.9 
 
Performing cross-validation optimisation of a boosted regression tree model 
for STRUCTURE.MOST and using a family of bernoulli 
Using 112 observations and 9 predictors 
creating 10 initial models of 50 trees 

 folds are stratified by prevalence 
total mean deviance =  NA 
tolerance is fixed at  NA 
ntrees resid. dev. 
Error in gbm.fit(x = x, y = y, offset = offset, distribution = distribution,  : 
  Bernoulli requires the response to be in {0,1}
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(y.data) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In Ops.factor(y.data, site.weights) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(y_i, log(u_i)) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
4: In Ops.factor(1, y_i) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Don't use the "RStudio" tag unless its a problem with the RStudio interface. I've changed to the "R" tag.

Comment: The first error is that `Bernoulli requires the response to be in {0,1}`. Is your response variable all zeroes and ones? Can we have some sample data or at least the basic summary information for your data?

Comment: @Spacedman Sorry, I should have included a bit more information. All of my dependent and independent variables are categorical. My dependent variables have between 3-5 levels and my independent variables have between 3-20 levels.

Comment: @spacedman  I wish to use the multinomial error family, not Bernoulli. However, the dismo package doesn't have this as an option. I have been told to leave the error family out of the code, and the gbm.step function will assume that my data is categorical, but this still does not work.

Comment: The help for `gbm.fit` talks about multinomial for factor responses, but this is `gbm.step`, which only allows binomial, poisson, gaussian and laplace responses according to ?gbm.fit. Are you confusing these, or are you trying to do what gbm.step does for a multinomial response?

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks, I am trying to do what gbm.step does for a multinomial reponse variable. My tutor suggested this analysis knowing that my data was categorical, so I'm a bit confused that it wont work.